# Superuser not prompting

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s, permissions, superuser

I recently installed ICS(Android 4) on my Samsung Galaxy S, and it seems that in the process my superuser app broke. Everything went fine, my phone is working better than ever, but when an app requires superuser permissions, it gets denied and I never get a prompt. Checked the settings, cleared superuser's cache and data, restarted it, tried to put it on automatically allow, nothing works.

How do I fix this?

P.S.
superuser has no problem prompting for itself(when updated it prompts "superuser asked for permissions"), but doesn't work for other apps.

Comment: Which ICS build did you install? Can you provide a link to the ROM (an XDA thread or such)?

Comment: I installed ICS 4.0.3 RC1. I can provide a link to the download, if you'd like, because I didn't follow a single guide to install it. It's this link if I'm not wrong: http://www.multiupload.com/UI9XV2OZJ7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build you flashed appears to have an [associated XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=20420260). The first post of that thread (by the ROM's creator) contains this a little ways down:

> **- Flash this if your are having root issues -**
>   http://goo-inside.me/superuser/Superuser-3.0.7-efghi-signed.zip

I'd start there, and see if it resolves the problem. You should just need to download the zip file and flash it from recovery (I can't test this myself, unfortunately. I don't own an SGS).

**Edit:** This looks like it may be a common problem with that particular build. There are some posts toward the end of the thread where people are saying they can't get root to work either. [Another post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20887553&postcount=2453) has a flashable zip file attached that is apparently intended to fix the issue as well.

Comment: Doing this right now, will update if it works.